# Can you use the Sweep Attack in Minecraft Pocket Edition, and if you can, how?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I just think it would be very useful information to know, as I have to deal with a large number of hostile mobs.

Answer (score 1):

No, [sweep attacks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sword#Sweep_attack) are only available in Java Edition.